# inserting multiple values in one shot and checking for duplicate at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello all i am inserting my data by this query

```
insert into doc_share (docid,did,coid,eid) values 
('$val','$some','$thing','$here'),
('$val25','$some','$thing','$here'),
('$val33','$some','$thing','$here')...
// only $val is changing other values are same
```

now in my database i want unique combination of `docid` and `did` i have done it from by table but i want to do it by query because even when there is one duplicate row no insertion of rows are done even for non duplicate rows.

i want to do the checking for any duplicate rows before sending the data to database if possible withing the same query

please give me some hints ....

Comment: This is one query, this isn't multi-querying. Is `docid` not auto-incrementing?

Comment: docid not auto-incrementing

Comment: oo `did` is a field not the word.. is `did` = `$some`? You have 4 values but 5 columns..

Comment: yes did is a  field not a word and i am sorry i edited the code 4 values 4 columns ..:)

Comment: i just need to check the combination of docid and did to be unique docid can be anything but did is same

Comment: Give it a unique constraint see this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert IGNORE into doc_share (docid,did,coid,eid) values 
('$val','$some','$thing','$here'),
('$val25','$some','$thing','$here'),
('$val33','$some','$thing','$here')...
```

Comment: it will still increment the auto incremented field ..

Comment: there is no "proper" way to not increment autoincrement-field. Forget about it. Somthing wrong with your app-logic if you want to do that